# XML Serialization Error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize XML, but I receive this error:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'responseReturnSalesOrder[]' to
>   'responseReturnSalesOrder'
>
> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'responseReturnSalesOrder' to 'responseReturnSalesOrder[]'

My xml contains an element called  and it appears I cannot parse it.

XML is here:

http://pastebin.com/3HD15Syv

Proxy class is here:

http://pastebin.com/M8HP7k9s

I found some weird code:

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("salesOrder", typeof(responseReturnSalesOrder), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
public responseReturnSalesOrder[][] @return {
    get {
        return this.returnField;
    }
    set {
        this.returnField = value;
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
StringReader _InXml = new StringReader(responseData);
XmlSerializer _oxs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));
response _Response = new response();
_Response = (response)_oxs.Deserialize(_InXml);
```

Comment: If you try removing the double `[][]` does it work (from all references)? I have this issue sometimes when creating a mapping file using the XML.

Comment: Note: When I say remove, change it to a single `[]`.

Comment: I will post it as a an answer for you to accept then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `public responseReturnSalesOrder[][]` should not be a multi dimensional array.

Change it to `public responseReturnSalesOrder[]` and it should work. I find this issue happens when creating mapping files using xsd.exe from XML / XSD's.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue after creating an XSD from an XML file and then creating the class from XSD with XSD.EXE. This seems to be a bug in XSD.EXE...